# How to change ID field behavior after sonata:admin:generate

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a fresh admin controller that extends Sonata's CRUDController class. I generated it using the `sonata:admin:generate` command.

There is also a new PostAdmin.php file that defines several field behaviors.

Here is a look at the table used by the entity:

```
mysql> DESC post;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body   | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is: **How do I go about making the ID field auto-populate in my CMS?**

Right now, it shows up as a normal int field that users have to fill out, which introduces lots of potential for skipped numbers (not to mention being annoying for the users). I would like to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieve this by [configuring the Form Mapper](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/the_form_view.html#configuring-the-form-mapper) of your `PostAdmin` class:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('body', 'textarea')
    ;
}
```

You would need to remove the `->add('id')` line so that it is not part of the form. Because it isn't necessary for the creation and should not be edited anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the field in that definition (as you suggested) did the trick.(Interestingly, I had to add the "slug" bit back in to make the application happy.)